Search by field that contains button and mat-menu not showing inside of table
I am working on creating a Search by field that when clicked on will have a check box to search by address. It is a button with mat-menu component. I want to add it  inside of the app-table-actions components. Any time I try to add it inside of the app-table-actions tags it doesn't show at all but if I move it outside of the tags it shows above the table as seen in the image. I want the Search By field to be next to Filter Tags.

In the angular html file, I currently have the button and mat-menu inside of div tags above the app-table actions.
 <div aria-label="View columns"
  class="d-flex align-content-center view-columns mr-3">
  <button class="mr-0 btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex flex-nowrap text-nowrap"
          [disabled]="searchFields.length === 0"
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="searchByMenu">
    <mat-icon>filter_alt</mat-icon>
    <span class="mx-1">{{ 'Search by field' }}</span>
 </button>

 <mat-menu
    #searchByMenu="matMenu"
    [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <ng-template [ngForOf]="searchFields" let-column ngFor>
        <div *ngIf="(column.field !== undefined)"
             mat-menu-item>
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="selectedSearchFields.isSelected(column)"
                          (change)="selectedSearchFields.toggle(column); 
        getUnitList()"
                          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
            >
                <span class="select-column-label">{{ column.label }}</span>
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
</div>
  <app-table-actions actionsType="primary"
               [(searchValue)]="searchValue"
               (searchValueChange)="searchValue = $event; searchChanged.emit()">


<lf-tags taggableType="Owner"
         taggableMode="Filter"
         placeholder="Filter Tags..."
         [hasArchived]="membersStatusFilter === 'archived'"
         (itemAdded)="selectedTags.select($event); loadPeople.emit()"
         (itemChange)="selectedTags.updateFilter($event); loadPeople.emit()"
         (itemRemoved)="selectedTags.deselect($event); loadPeople.emit()"
         (itemsCleared)="selectedTags.clear(); loadPeople.emit()">
</lf-tags>


<app-selection-button *ngIf="selection.hasValue()"
                      (onClick)="showSelectedMembers.emit()">
    {{ selection.selected.length }}
</app-selection-button>

<app-button *ngIf="jwt.admin || jwt.superUser"
            [svg]="'settings'"
            [iconClasses]="['mr-1']"
            [routeTo]="'/app/settings/organization/permissions'">
    {{ 'Manage Permissions' }}
</app-button>

<app-add-button *ngIf="hasWriteAccess"
                [buttonClasses]="['mr-0']"
                [routeTo]="['/app/owner/create']">
    {{ 'Add Owners' }}
</app-add-button>

<ng-container *mobileActions>
    <button *ngIf="jwt.admin || jwt.superUser" 
  [routerLink]="'/app/settings/organization/permissions'" mat-menu-item>{{ 'Manage 
  Permissions' }}</button>
    <button *ngIf="hasWriteAccess" [routerLink]="['/app/owner/create']" mat-menu- 
       item>.  {{ 'Add Owners' }}</button>
</ng-container>
 </app-table-actions>

 <div class="payhoa-table-responsive fadeIn animated" [class.no-scroll]="(isLoading || 
     (tableDataSource.loading$ | async))">
 <mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource"
           [trackBy]="trackMember"
           class="payhoa-table"
           matSort
           matSortActive="name"
           matSortDirection="asc"
           matSortDisableClear="true"
           (contentChanged)="loadingState$.next(false); contentChanged.emit()">
    <!-- render templates -->
    <ng-template #emptyCell><span class="add-ashy-blue">--</span></ng-template>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="isAllSelected()"
                          [indeterminate]="hasASelection() && !isAllSelected()"
                          (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"></mat-checkbox>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                          (change)="$event ? toggleSelection(row) : null"></mat- 
    checkbox>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Name' }}</mat-header- 
     cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <app-button type="link"
                        [buttonClasses]="['mr-0']"
                        [routerLink]="['/app/members/' + row.id]">
                {{ row.name }}
            </app-button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Email' }}</mat-header- 
     cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <span *ngIf="row.email; else emptyCell" class="w-100">
                {{ row.email }}
            </span>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-shorter" mat-sort-header> 
    {{ 'Owner Status' }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-column-shorter">{{ row.status }} 
   </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="permission">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-shorter" mat-sort-header 
      >{{ 'Permissions' }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="mat-column-shorter">
            {{ row.permission }}
        </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastLogin">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Last login' }}</mat- 
    header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <ng-template #neverLoginCell><span class="add-ashy-blue">{{ 'Never' }} 
    </span></ng-template>
            <span *ngIf="row.lastLogin; else neverLoginCell">{{ row.lastLogin | 
     legfiDate:'MM/DD/YYYY' }}</span>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="unitsString">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ 'Units' }}</mat-header- 
      cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <ng-container *ngIf="row.units.length > 0; else emptyCell">
                <span class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let unit of row.units">
                        <app-unit-button [unit]="unit"
                                         [isDisabled]="!hasUnitAccess"
                                         [routeTo]="'/app/unit/detail/' + unit.id"> 
      </app-unit-button>
                    </ng-container>
                </span>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="tags">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'Tags' }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let member">
             <lf-tags *ngIf="!isLoading && !(tableDataSource.loading$ | async)"
                      taggableType="Owner"
                      taggableMode="Table"
                      [doSuppressHoverButton]="true"
                      [taggableId]="member.id"
                      [isEditable]="true"
                      [hasArchived]="membersStatusFilter === 'archived'"
                      [(items)]="member.tags">
             </lf-tags>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'Actions' }}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <ng-container *ngIf="actionsTemplate">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="actionsTemplate; context: { member: 
       row }"></ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <div *matNoDataRow class="table-row mat-empty">
        <app-jumbotron [headerText]="isLoading || (tableDataSource.loading$ | async) ? 
      ' ' : 'No owners to display.'"
                       [classList]="['mx-5']"
                       [showEmptyImg]="false">
        </app-jumbotron>
    </div>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header- 
  row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>


<!-- loading -->
<div *ngIf="isLoading || (tableDataSource.loading$ | async)" class="payhoa-loading 
      animate fadeIn">
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="60"
                 [strokeWidth]="8"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
</div>

   <mat-paginator [disabled]="isLoading || (tableDataSource.loading$ | async)"
           [length]="totalRecords"
           [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [pageSize]="pageSize"
           (page)="loadingState$.next(true)">
   </mat-paginator>

app-table-actions component typescript
 @Directive({
    selector: '[actions]',
   })
  export class TableActionsDirective
    {
    constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>) {
    }
  }

 @Directive({
   selector: '[mobileActions]',
  })
  export class TableActionsMobileDirective
   {
    constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>) {
   }
  }

 @Directive({
    selector: '[bulkActions]',
   })
 export class TableBulkActionsDirective
   {
   constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>) {
   }
 }

@Component({
   selector: 'app-table-actions',
   templateUrl: './table-actions.component.html',
   })
export class TableActionsComponent implements OnChanges
 {
// search, if applicable
 @Input() searchValue: string;
 @Output() searchValueChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

// columns menu
@Input() tableType: TableTypeNames;
@Input() columnMap: ColumnMap[];
@Input() newColumnButton = false;
@Input() selectedColumns: SelectionModel<TableColumn>;
@Output() selectedColumnsChange: EventEmitter<SelectionModel<TableColumn>> = new 
EventEmitter<SelectionModel<TableColumn>>();

// actions menu
@Input() selectionCount = 0;
@Input() actionsType: ButtonType = 'default';

// ng-content for mat-menu-items and bulk actions
@ContentChild(TableActionsDirective) items!: TableActionsDirective;
@ContentChild(TableActionsMobileDirective) mobileItems!: TableActionsMobileDirective;
@ContentChild(TableBulkActionsDirective) bulkActionItems!: TableBulkActionsDirective;

showSearch = false;

constructor(private _host: HostListenerService) {
}

get availableColumns() {
    return this.columnMap.filter((column) => {
        if (!column.title) {
            return false;
        }

        if (column.disabled) {
            return !column.disabled();
        }

        return true;
    });
}

get actionsLabel() {
    return `Actions${this.selectionCount > 0 ? ' (' + this.selectionCount + ')' : 
 ''}`;
}

get mobileMode$() {
    return this._host.isMobileMode();
}

get tabletMode$() {
    return this._host.isTabletMode();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes.hasOwnProperty('searchValue')) {
        this.showSearch = true;
    }

    if (changes && changes.hasOwnProperty('columnMap')) {
        const keys = ColumnService.read(this.tableType);
        if (keys) {
            const values = this.columnMap.filter((column) => {
                return keys.indexOf(column.key) > -1;
            });

            this.selectedColumns.select(...values);
        } else {
            this.resetColumns();
        }
    }
}

search(term = '') {
    this.searchValue = term;
    this.searchValueChange.emit(term);
}

resetColumns() {
    const values = this.columnMap.filter((column) => {
        if (column.defaultShow) {
            return !!column.defaultShow();
        }

        return true;
    });

    this.selectedColumns.select(...values);
    ColumnService.clear(this.tableType);
}

storeColumns() {
     ColumnService.store(this.tableType, this.selectedColumns.selected);
   }
 }

I've tried moving the div tags at the beginning inside the app-table-actions tag it doesn't show on the page. I tried moving just the button and mat-menu without the div tags and it doesn't show. Do I need to create a separate component for the button and mat-menu? Or could it be an issue with the app-table-actions?

Can anyone help with this please.

PLEASE GIVE SOME CODE SNIPT IN STACKBLIZ
